# How do i let search engines to display products from my website?

Tags: php, mysql, seo, query-string, search-engine

I am not talking about search engine indexing of static pages like about.html, services.html.  Let's say i sell products and each product is displayed by going to link: domain.com/product.php?id=343.

Is there something i have to do coding-wise to achieve this or is it more of a search engine specific thing? I use PHP/MYSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search engines can crawl and index pages with query strings just fine so you don't have to do anything special for them. Just make sure they can find those pages either through HTML links or an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/).

See our sister site [Pro Webmasters for more on SEO and query strings](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bseo%5D%20query%20strings)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, search engines *(well, spiders that do the indexation)* will tend to follow links that are present inside the pages of your website -- pretty much like a real user would do, actually.

So, if you have a home page that links to several category page, each one containing links to the products pages, search engines will be able to find out the URLs of those pages -- and index them.

You can also, to help them, build a [**sitemap**](http://www.sitemaps.org/) file -- which, basically, will contain the URL of all pages of your website.